# How to make vuetify v-menu items navigatable with tab-key

Tags: vuetify.js, accessibility

I have a Vuetify application that has been reviewed for accessibility (WCAG 2.1 AA). One of the issues that was found was that my v-app-bar menus are not navigable with the tab-key, only with the arrow keys.

Currently, my menus are like this:

```
  <v-menu offset-y>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-btn v-on="on" outlined>Menu one</v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-list>
      <v-list-item-group>
        <v-list-item>
          <v-list-item-title @click="menuclicked">Option one</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
        <v-list-item>
          <v-list-item-title>Option two</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-menu>
```

codepen with two menus: https://codepen.io/theocodepen/pen/QWMyRbr

However, the accessibility report states that once a menu is open, the tab key should go through the menu items, not to the next menu button.

So if I click on 'Menu one', then press tab, 'option one' should be selected, not 'menu two' (and 'option two' on the next tab).

So far, I have been unable to create that behaviour, does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/application-menus/#top-level-menu-items

Comment: Are you suggesting that the auditor is wrong, or that i should not use v-menu for things that may not immediately seem like 'top level menus' (such as a language selection pulldown on the top-right)?

Comment: Are you using this component for the primary site navigation, or is it on the header bar of a widget for further actions etc? Either way they auditor is wrong as they should either have told you to use a different element (if it is site navigation) or they should not have suggested the drop-down list should work with Tab as this is incorrect. Let us know how you are using the component for and we will be able to help further (p.s. your button that opens the drop-down is missing some WAI-ARIA attributes as far as I can see, `aria-owns`, `aria-haspopup` and `aria-expanded` appear to be missing.)

Comment: Yes the missing aria attributes were another issue, thanks for mentioning those. The components are not for main navigation (that is done with a drawer on the left of the screen). They are on the top right and globally present in the v-app-bar; one menu is to manage the login session (the pulldown shows user information and a logout button), and the other is to change the language of the application (showing a list of supported languages). I have asked for clarification, and the auditor claims the WAI description should only be used for real menus (File, Edit, ...).

Comment: You must use the attach prop. This will ensure that focus transfers from the activator to the content when pressing the tab key. https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/client-side-script/SCR26

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it now by overriding specific events, giving me the behaviour that was requested:

For the menu:

```
<v-menu ref="menuOne" offset-y>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <v-btn v-on:keydown.tab="menuTabPressed"
           v-on:click="on.click"
           v-on:keydown.enter="on.keydown"
           v-on:keydown.up="on.keydown"
           v-on:keydown.down="on.keydown"
           data-menu="menuOne"
           :v-bind="attrs"
           outlined>
      Menu one
    </v-btn>
  </template>
  <v-list>
    <!-- items go here -->
```

The event handler function for the tab key:

```
menuTabPressed: function(event) {
  let menu = this.$refs[event.target.dataset.menu];
  // make sure children are evaluated
  menu.getTiles();
  // In most cases, we want the event to be stopped,
  // however, in the cases where we tab 'out of' the menu,
  // we want to propagate the event.
  let propagate = false;

  if (menu.isActive) {
      if (event.shiftKey) {
        if (menu.listIndex <= 0) {
          menu.isActive = false;
          propagate = true;
        } else {
          menu.prevTile();
        }
      } else {
        if (menu.listIndex < 0) {
          menu.firstTile();
        } else if (menu.listIndex + 1 >= menu.tiles.length) {
          menu.isActive = false;
          propagate = true;
        } else {
          menu.nextTile()
        }
      }
  } else {
    propagate = true;
  }
  if (!propagate) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
},
```

Codepen with full example: https://codepen.io/theocodepen/pen/YzxWLLM